# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_list'

Tags: python, forecasting

Getting the error like TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model_list'

When I am running following script:

```
from autots import AutoTS

model_list = ['LastValueNaive','GLS','ETS','AverageValueNaive',]

model = AutoTS(\
forecast_length=49,\
frequency='infer',\
prediction_interval=0.95,\
ensemble=\['simple', 'horizontal-min'\],\
max_generations=5,\
num_validations=2,\
validation_method='seasonal 168',\
model_list=model_list,\
transformer_list='all',\
models_to_validate=0.2,\
drop_most_recent=1,\
n_jobs='auto',
)
```

I have taken the script from the AutoTS documentation only.I have n't changed anything but getting error.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape newlines inside an argument list.

Comment: "I have taken the script from the AutoTS documentation only." Can you please show this documentation?

Comment: https://winedarksea.github.io/AutoTS/build/html/source/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Try without making strings in model_list like so:

```
model_list = [LastValueNaive,GLS,ETS,AverageValueNaive]
```

This approach worked for me when using neuralforecast, mlforecast from Nixtla. Maybe it works for you too.